# Code copied one-to-one from the textbook does absolutely nothing

Tags: c++, opencv, video

I wrote the following code from a tutorial textbook:

```
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
using namespace cv;


/* 

Displays a video with a trackbar

*/


int         g_slider_position = 0;
CvCapture*  g_capture         = NULL;

void onTrackbarSlide(int pos){
    cvSetCaptureProperty(
        g_capture,
        CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,
        pos
    );

} 

int main( int argc, char** argv){
    cvNamedWindow( "Example 3", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    g_capture = cvCreateFileCapture( argv[1] );
    int frames = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty(
        g_capture,
        CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT
    );
    if( frames!= 0 ){
        cvCreateTrackbar(
            "Position",
            "Example 3",
            &g_slider_position,
            frames,
            onTrackbarSlide
        );
    }
    IplImage* frame;
    return (0);
}
```

and except for the `using namespace cv;` and the comment, It's one-to-one for every character. I compiled it with this:

```
g++ CVB--02-TrackBarVid.cpp -o CVB--02-TrackBarVid  `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

and when I ran it with a short animated video clip... Absolutely nothing happened. It's supposed to display a video with a scroll bar, and what makes it even more strange is that an earlier program that did nothing but play a video worked fine, even when I changed it so that the video was only 640x480.

What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided actually does something, but not much - it displays an empty window named "Example 3" and immediately exits.

What it does it checks the number of frames in your video and puts it into the `frames` variable. If there are any frames in the provided video file it creates a trackbar. But after that nothing happens. this code lacks video processing like taking frames from the video file. You can see that there is a pointer declared `IplImage* frame;` which is left uninitialized and the program ends with `return (0);`. There at least should be a loop going from 0 (first frame) to `frames-1` (last frame) taking each frame from the video and putting it to the "Example 3" window.

This code looks like a bad "copy-paste" or something...

Comment: Yep, that was it: I mistook a comment in the book as an instruction, instead of a prompt to *fill in the missing code myself*.  Thanks for clarifying that for me, you really  helped.